# Instrumented Testing with Dagger2 - how to reference fake repository?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvvm

My goal is to test an app with Espresso.

First Screen Activity depends on settings received from a Repository. Repository checks whether the user saved a location preference in Shared Preferences. If he has, it moves on to the Main Activity. That's the part of logic that I am trying to test.

I want to substitute fake repository (HashMap representing shared preferences) to achieve consistency. Tests run and pass if the repository is empty (base state). However, I want to test whether the app moves forward if the location is saved.

Test in question:

```
@Test
fun onLaunch_withLocationSaved_checkMainActivityIsShown() {
    fakeRepository.saveLocation("40,80")

    ActivityScenario.launch(FirstScreenActivity::class.java)
    onView(withText(R.string.welcome_message)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
}
```

How do I get a reference to fakeRepository to be able to save location that ViewModel will read from?

If it's created (which defeats the point of injection) like this:

```
@Before
fun init() {
    fakeRepository = FakeSimpleRepository()
    fakeRepository.saveLocation("")
    viewModel = FirstScreenViewModel(fakeRepository)
}
```

The viewmodel gets injected with a different fakeRepository object (I compared addresses with a debugger).

I followed Google's codelabs and official documentation how to set up Dagger with my app. Their examples do not show how to reference the repository though to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://proandroiddev.com/unit-tests-with-dagger2-retrofit2-rxjava2-and-mockk-android-1c268fa77957) blog cover what you want to achieve

The idea is that you have to override your dagger module to inject the mock object. Then you create a custom runner class to override the application class.

Comment: I already have the custom runner and tests run, objects gets injected. However a different object gets injected in the viewmodel constructor and a different object gets injected in the test class even though the fake repository should be a singleton. That's the issue I am having